# How to call controller's method in jQuery/ajax url in rails?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I want to create and save data into cart model using jQuery/Ajax so, I want to call the controller's method in Ajax URL.

jQuery/Ajax script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.add-cart-product').click(function() {
  var product_id = $('.simpleCart_shelfItem').data('product');
  var user_id = $('.simpleCart_shelfItem').data('user');
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: "/front/carts/add_cart",
    data: {
      product_id: product_id,
      user_id: user_id
    },
    success: function(data) {}
  });
 })
})
```

`carts_controller.rb`:

```
def add_cart
  @cart = Cart.new(:user_id => params[:user_id],:product_id => params[:product_id] )
  @cart.save
end
```

`model/cart.rb`:

```
class Cart < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :products
  has_many :users
end
```

`routes.rb`:

```
namespace :front do
  resources :carts do
    collection do
      get 'add_cart'
    end  
  end
end
```

These are all the routes which are generated from `rake routes` :

```
aspireedge@aspireedge-H81M-S:~/Projects/Ronak/store$ rake routes | grep carts
                 front_carts_show GET        /front/carts/show(.:format)                      front/carts#show
         batch_action_admin_carts POST       /admin/carts/batch_action(.:format)              admin/carts#batch_action
                      admin_carts GET        /admin/carts(.:format)                           admin/carts#index
                                  POST       /admin/carts(.:format)                           admin/carts#create
                   new_admin_cart GET        /admin/carts/new(.:format)                       admin/carts#new
                  edit_admin_cart GET        /admin/carts/:id/edit(.:format)                  admin/carts#edit
                       admin_cart GET        /admin/carts/:id(.:format)                       admin/carts#show
                                  PATCH      /admin/carts/:id(.:format)                       admin/carts#update
                                  PUT        /admin/carts/:id(.:format)                       admin/carts#update
                                  DELETE     /admin/carts/:id(.:format)                       admin/carts#destroy
                      front_carts GET        /front/carts(.:format)                           front/carts#index
                                  POST       /front/carts(.:format)                           front/carts#create
                   new_front_cart GET        /front/carts/new(.:format)                       front/carts#new
                  edit_front_cart GET        /front/carts/:id/edit(.:format)                  front/carts#edit
                       front_cart GET        /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#show
                                  PATCH      /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#update
                                  PUT        /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#update
                                  DELETE     /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#destroy
             add_cart_front_carts POST       /front/carts/add_cart(.:format)                  front/carts#add_cart
                                  GET        /front/carts(.:format)                           front/carts#index
                                  POST       /front/carts(.:format)                           front/carts#create
                                  GET        /front/carts/new(.:format)                       front/carts#new
                                  GET        /front/carts/:id/edit(.:format)                  front/carts#edit
                                  GET        /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#show
                                  PATCH      /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#update
                                  PUT        /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#update
                                  DELETE     /front/carts/:id(.:format)                       front/carts#destroy
```

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get any error?

Comment: no not getting any error but URL not redirect to controller's method.

Comment: run `rake routes` and paste the result here

Comment: Is the JS even firing? Put a breakpoint and check whether that function being triggered or not.

Comment: @RonakBhatt check my post

Comment: Is the request type correct? I mean u r trying to put the data rather than getting it, don't you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below code to solve issue of `authenticity token`:

```
class CartsController < ApplicationController
  protect_from_forgery except: "add_cart"

  def add_cart
   ...
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can actually have your ajax requests include the token, something like:

views/layout/application.html.erb

```
<meta name="authenticity-token" content="<%= form_authenticity_token %>" />
```

assets/javascript/application.js (assuming jQuery)

```
$(function(){
    $.ajaxSetup({
      headers: { 'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="authenticity-token"]').attr('content') }
  });
});
```